# Choosing which JVM to use in Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, jvm

I have Java 1.6 and Java 1.7 in different directories (/usr/java) and a soft link pointing to one of them (the one I wish to use at that time).

i.e.:

```
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  root  4096 Jan 31 12:16 ./
drwxr-xr-x 11 root  root  4096 Jan 30 12:52 ../
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  root     6 Jan 31 12:16 default -> java6//
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  root    12 Jan 31 12:15 java6 -> jdk1.6.0_37//
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  root    12 Jan 31 12:15 java7 -> jdk1.7.0_11//
drwxr-xr-x  8 david david 4096 Jan 30 18:16 jdk1.6.0_37/
drwxr-xr-x  8 david david 4096 Jan 31 12:14 jdk1.7.0_11/
```

This means I can just change where the default link points and I change where my JAVA_HOME points.

My system is, however, overrun with OpenJDK and Iced tea.  I've removed them (I think) so not I have no system java at all.

My question is, how do I make my system look for Java where the default link is pointing?

Thank all

Dave

Comment: `PATH`? `JAVA_HOME`? Need a bit more detail on what you mean by "...make my system look for Java..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just followed the steps on this blog:

[How to Install Oracle Java on Ubuntu Linux: 18 steps](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux)

and it seems to have done what I'd like.

Thanks to all for the advise though.

Answer (score 2):

1. sudo update-alternatives --config java
2. choose java version
3. in project settings set with wich jdk you want work

Answer (score 0):

These links can help you out:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/199065/replacing-the-openjdk-with-the-oracle-jdk
- http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Install-Oracle-Java-in-Ubuntu-309861.shtml

Answer (score 0):

If you do not like the terminal, there is a GUI for this stuff: `galternatives`. It is very easy to use.